# How to resolve the correct type from the container (static type vs runtime type)?

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a problem with resolving a dependency in [autofac](/questions/tagged/autofac). It may be related to co/contra variance on type.

The following program returns 0, 1. Which means that the two call to resolve does not returns the same types (whhereas it is the same object that serves to get the type) I would expect it to return: 1,1. (The difference is that the static type of my var is different, is there a way to use the runtime type ?)

Thanks

```
IContainer _container;

void Main()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<AHandler>().As<IHandler<A>>();
    _container = builder.Build();

    IBase a = new A();
    Console.WriteLine(Resolve(a));
    A b = new A();
    Console.WriteLine(Resolve(b));
}

int Resolve<T>(T a) where T:IBase
{
    return _container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IHandler<T>>>().Count();
}

// Define other methods and classes here
interface IBase{}
interface IHandler<T> where T:IBase {}

class A : IBase{}

class AHandler : IHandler<A>{}
```

Comment: refer a link http://www.dotnetperls.com/dynamic

Comment: I am looking at a statically typed solution (though using reflection is probably not that different than using dynamic).

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do some sort of runtime resolution of the type. E.g. using the [`dynamic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) keyword:

```
IBase a = new A();
Console.WriteLine(Resolve((dynamic)a));
A b = new A();
Console.WriteLine(Resolve((dynamic)b));
```

Or using reflection:

```
int ResolveDynamic(IBase a)
{
    MethodInfo method = typeof(IContainer).GetMethod("Resolve");
    var handlerType = typeof(IHandler<>).MakeGenericType(a.GetType());
    var enumerableType = typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(handlerType);
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(enumerableType);

    var result = (IEnumerable<object>)generic.Invoke(_container, null);
    return result.Count();
}
```

Comment: It is interesting but I have to say that I was expecting another solution. Something based on ContravariantRegistrationSource for inst. This is maybe a limitation of C# generic but still looking for a solution... I think this is in int Resolve<T>(T a) where T:IBase that is something wrong

Comment: @Dave the interface you show is not contravariant (e.g. `in T`). As it is, `IHandler<A>` and `IHandler<T> where T : IBase` have to be treated as very distinct entities. Is your `IHandler` interface actually `<in T>` (or can it compile as such?), or just `<T>`?

Comment: Right now there is no in or out modifier, but I was wondering if adding one of these would solve my issue. I have some issues understanding the exact meaning and usage of these keywords. And being stuck with I thought it might help or solve the issue.